# Facebook iframe comment flyout appears below other elements

Tags: iframe, facebook-like

Searched pretty extensively for a solution to this, I don't think I'm duplicating an already asked question...

I was experiencing a problem where the facebook like flyout box appeared below other elements on my [page](http://expeditions.daattravel.com/). The problem is, I'm using a theme with a two column layout, so when you like something on the left column, it would appear below the elements on the right column.

I tried to play with the z-index for `iframe`, but that made the facebook button on both columns rise to the top, making the comment flyover appear above all elements *except* the right column facebook button, which now appears above it.

Using the ShareThis plugin, which uses the iframe facebook like button.

Can this work? Or do I need to find a plugin that uses XFBML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up and solved this by using a workaround. I eliminated one of the 4 sharing options and spaced the like button so the flyout would conflict with any other element.

It seems to be a specific issue with the ShareThis plugin I'm using on wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

This is the fix...

```
.fb-like iframe 
{
max-width: inherit;
z-index: 1000;
}
```